# Administrative IT Scripts (security issues)

Tags: security, scripting, database-administration

I am doing homework and having a hard time finding the information I need; I am just looking for some guidance. I need to identify some administrative IT tasks that use scripting, but the script used causes some type of security issue. What would be the issue and how would the issue be solved? Summary, keywords, links, anything would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of something I could imagine some ignorant it guy doing...

Write a php script where you pass a path of where you a database backed up to.  Then an adversary could pass a path inside the HTML document root.  I could then download the entire database to my computer.

Might not be the best example but it happens.